Convergence of probability measure with bounded second order momentum
We denote by ${\mathcal P}_1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ the set of Borel probability measures $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with a finite first order moment $M_1(\nu)$:
$$
M_1(\nu)= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |x-x_0|d\nu(x)<+\infty
$$
for some (and thus all) $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^d$. The set  ${\mathcal P}_1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is endowed with the Monge-Kantorovitch distance:
$$
{\bf d}_1(\nu_1,\nu_2)= \sup_{\phi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\phi(x)d(\nu_1-\nu_2)(x) \qquad \forall \nu_1,\nu_2\in  {\mathcal P}_1(\mathbb{R}^d),
$$
where the supremum is taken over all 1-Lipschitz continuous maps $\phi:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$. I am trying to prove the following result.
If $\mu\in {\mathcal P}_1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\mu_n\in {\mathcal P}_1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is a sequence with a bounded second order momentum and s.t.
$$
\lim_n  \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \Phi(x)d\mu_n(x)= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \Phi(x)d\mu(x),
 $$
for any bounded and continuous maps $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$. Then $\mu_n$ converges to $\mu$ in ${\mathcal P}_1(\mathbb{R}^d)$,

$\mu_n$ converges to $\mu$ iff it converges weakly and the first order moments converge as well. If the second order moment is bounded then so is the first order moment and the result is straightforward. Why bother with bounded second order moment? Where does this exercise come from?

Thanks, I didn't know this result! I am agree with you, we need just bounded first order moment. But, why if the first order moments is bounded, then the first order moments of \mu_n converge to the first order momento of \mu?

Because then you can choose the continuous and bounded map $\Phi(x)=\vert x\vert\wedge M$ where $M$ is the upper bound.
